# Derivative and lipschitz

Tags: analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence

If I have a real-valued continuous function defined on a compact subset of real line, such that its derivative(wherever it exists) is bounded. Is such a function necessarily Lipschitz?

Additionally, this came to my mind while I was searching for the weakest condition on a continuous function on a compact set such that it is also lipschitz.

Does there exist a weaker result than wanting the derivatives to be continuous on the interval(with continuous extension at the end points of the interval) ?

Comment: For $f:A\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the set $A$ has to be open for $f$ to be differentiable on it. You just need $A$ to be bounded and $f'$ to be bounded on $A$. Then (and only then), yes, $f$ is Lipschitz on $A$.

Answer (score 2):

If the set is convex and the derivative exists everywhere then the Mean Value Theorem will give you the desired result.

Comment: If we assume the derivative to exist everywhere on the compact set then convexity must be able to supply the fact that derivative is bounded. But since you have written that the 'the set is convex' ,do you meant the function to be convex on the interval or interval itself to convex(which it is always)?

Comment: @user2902293 I meant that the domain of the function must be convex. In your question you only mention that the domain is a compact set, not necessarily a convex set or an interval. Could you please clarify how convexity of the domain ensures boundedness?

Comment: i am sorry, i was always talking about a compact subset of the real line. i have edited the question.